# Choosing an STL container to store threads

Tags: c++, containers

I am trying to choose the best STL container to hold Thread objects (I am writing a thread library). My problem is that I'm not very familiar with any of them, and while reading the api helps, I would like to consult someone who had used it before.

Anyway - every `Thread` object has two important attributes: `_id` and `_priority`.
I need to be able to access a thread by `_id`, so I naturally thought of a hash_map. I also want the objects to be sorted by `_priority` (different Thread objects can have the same priority), so I thought of a priority queue with pointers to the hash_map, but if I delete a thread who's not first on the queue it gets a little ugly.

Is there a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have two different usages, one where you want to look up a particular thread, and another where you want to loop over everything in a particular order?

Answer (score 4):

To get two types of access you either need to combine two containers... or reuse a library that combines containers for you.

[Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) was invented for precisely this kind of needs.

The [basics page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html) shows an example that has employees accessible by id (unique) and sorted by name (non-unique), which is pretty much what you are going for.

The key extractors are perhaps not obvious. Supposing that your thread ressemble:

```
class Thread {
public:
    std::size_t id() const;
    std::size_t priority() const;

    ...
};
```

You should be able to write:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/const_mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

// define a multiply indexed set with indices by id and name
typedef multi_index_container<
    Thread,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<
            const_mem_fun<Thread, std::size_t, &Thread::id>
        >,
        ordered_non_unique<
            const_mem_fun<Thread, std::size_t, &Thread::priority>
        >
    > 
> ThreadContainer;
```

Which defines a container of thread uniquely identified by their `id()` and sorted according to their `priority()`.

I encourage you to play around with the various indexes. Also, if you provide friend access to your class or specific getters that return mutable references, then using `mem_fun` instead of `const_mem_fun` you will be able to update your objects in place (for example, change their priority).

It's a very complete (if daunting) library.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is possibly [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/),, providing you a key / value pair. In your scenario the key has the type of your `_id` and the value the type `Thread` (assuming this is the name of your class). By copying all values to a `std::vector` you can sort by `_priority` with `std::sort` and a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to keep the `std::unordered_map` to provide the key --> thread lookup, and then use a `std::set` to implement your priority queue.